# SettingWithCopyWarning: conditionally updating [i] with [i-1]+1 python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (and approx 6000 rows) as shown:

```
head_ma  rec_time
NaN      1.0
8.20     1.0
8.21     1.0
8.22     1.0
8.23     1.0
8.21     1.0
8.20     1.0
8.19     1.0
8.20     1.0
...      ...
```

And I'm trying to loop through each `[i]` in the `head_ma` column in my dataframe and where `[i] < [(i-1)]`, I want to update `[i]` in the `rec_time` column with `[i-1]+1`. The code I currently have works, but I get the error: "SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

How can I update my current code to avoid this please?

Current code:

```
for i in range (2, len(df)):
        if df.head_ma[i] < df.head_ma[(i-1)]:
            df.rec_time[i] = (df.rec_time[i-1]+1)
```

Comment: Try using `df.loc[i, ''rec_time"]`

Comment: @quest As you weren't quite clear I tried `df.loc[i, "rec_time"] = (df.rec_time[i-1]+1)` and got the error: 'int' object has no attribute 'view'. I also tried `df.loc[i, "rec_time"] = (df.loc[(i-1), "rec_time"]+1)` which returned the error: TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [124] of <class 'int'>

Comment: ```for i in range (2, len(df)):
        if df.head_ma[i] < df.head_ma[(i-1)]:
            df.loc[i, 'rec_time'] = (df.rec_time[i-1]+1)``` <-- could you try this